Getting torchtext.legacy module not found error
I have found a Language Detection model in github and I want to try it. It was written using torchtext 0.11. When I try to run it with torchtext 0.18 installed, I get torchtext.legacy module not found error even though torchtext is installed. Is there any way to solve this? Vocabs is the trained data file.
vocabs = torch.load('./data/vocabs')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\\\\Programming\intro-to-ai\new_lang\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1025, in lo
ad                                                                                                                                             return _load(opened_zipfile,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\\\\Programming\intro-to-ai\new_lang\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1446, in _l
oad                                                                                                                                            result = unpickler.load()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\\\\Programming\intro-to-ai\new_lang\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 1439, in fi
nd_class                                                                                                                                       return super().find_class(mod_name, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchtext.legacy'

I tried reverting torhtext to 0.6 but it didn't work.
